# Update json object value by key in a mysql field

Tags: mysql, json

I have this JSON data in a MySQL JSON field

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "col1":"col1_value",
      "col2":"col2_value"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "col1":"col1_value",
      "col2":"col2_value"
   }
]
```

How can i update col1 value to 'new col1 value' ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I use mysql 5.7.26